# Connection error while creating SQLServerBulkCopy object in java

Tags: java, sql, java-8, sql-server-2016, mssql-jdbc

Receiving following error upon creating SQLServerBulkCopy object:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Destination connection must be a connection from the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.
```

- Using 2016 SQL Server;
- connecting using SQL Authentication;
- Using mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar and JRE 1.8 versions.

The connection was successful but the SQLServerBulkCopy object creation is failing. Not sure why the connection is not an instance of SQLServerConnection.

Code used to create the connection and SQLServerBulkCopy object:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + serverName + ":1433;database=" + databaseName
                + ";user=xxxxxx;password=yyyyyyy";

        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ODSException("Unable to create connection to SQL Server.", e);
        }

        return connection;
    }

    private void executeBCP() throws ODSException {
        //Create a Connection and SQLServerBulkCopy objects
        try (Connection connection = JDBCUtil.getConnection();
                SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            boolean prevAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    //further code...

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            bcpLogger.error(e);

            throw new ODSException("Error bulk copying data to SQL Server.", e);
        }
```

From SQLServerBulkCopy source code, I see the constructor has the following code:

```
    public SQLServerBulkCopy(Connection connection) throws SQLServerException {
            loggerExternal.entering(loggerClassName, "SQLServerBulkCopy", connection);
            if (null == connection || !(connection instanceof SQLServerConnection)) {
                SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(null, null, SQLServerException.getErrString("R_invalidDestConnection"), null, false);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the code you have used to create the SQLServerBulkCopy object.

Comment: I used the standard call...

Edited in the main post...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Originally code would throw exception:

```
...
Connection connection = Manager.getInstance().getConnection();
SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy =  new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection);
```

Changed to fix

```
Connection connection = Manager.getInstance().getConnection().getMetaData().getConnection();
SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy =  new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection);
```